# Android: Keep Fragment (for ActionBar Tab) Running After Switching From The Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm creating an application that involves multiple fragments as tabs on actionbar.  I need to keep the processes for these fragments running while I switch tabs close the application (not end the application, but when pressing home or back I want the application to continue running in the background).  So to keep the fragments running while switching between tabs, I modified one of the sample TabListeners in the sdk to show and hide instead of attach and detach.  The code for that is:

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;


    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        this(activity, tag, clz, null);
    }

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isHidden()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.show(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.hide(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

And the tabs are created like this:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab aTab= actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab A").setTabListener(new TabListener<AFragment>(this, "AFrag", AFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(aTab);
    ActionBar.Tab bTab= actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab B").setTabListener(new TabListener<BFragment>(this, "BFrag", BFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(bTab);
```

So this seems to work, for switching the tabs at least.  Sometimes the fragments will appear on top of each other though, although that was with a different implementation of the TabListener and it hasn't occurred since, so it might be gone now.  I don't know why it occurred, so I don't know how I could replicate it.

It's pretty buggy when closing the app though.  Most of the time, when pressing home, the app will still work and be running when I open it up again.  Sometimes it doesn't though, which is weird.  Pressing back also closes the application, but starting it again seems to restart the application from the beginning, which is not desired.  Sometimes when pressing back from that it will go back to the previously running fragment.

It's pretty random and unstable though.  It's unpredictable when it will work or not.  What's the best way to go about this to improve the stability so that when it closes it continues to run, and reopening the application doesn't restart it?

Comment: You may find Fragments overlap when you use FragmentTransaction.add(..) as you have done. Try replacing this with FragmentTransaction.replace(..), as this seems to work better. Also having Fragments run in the background seems like quite bad practice, are you sure you can't work around this with, say, a background Service?

Comment: @Espiandev I'll look into using replace instead of add.  What's bad about having the fragments run in the background though?  What I mean is like, when I press home and then reopen the app then it takes back off from where it would be if it was continuing to run while after I pressed home (which it was).  Sometimes it seems to create a new fragment on top of that though?  But if I press back, then open it up again, it recreates the entire fragment rather than opening up the previous one, which I want it to do.  I do see how running a service could improve it, but is it necessary?

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you meant you want it to be _doing stuff_ in the background, apologies. Check out my answer for a couple of ideas.

Comment: In the above code, the number of tab is known,so we can create the fragment class according to that. If I am calling some method say addActionBarTab(), in runtime only the tabs are created. Then how can I dynamically create the fragment class specific for the tab which in the Action Bar. Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Activities, Fragments can save their state in a Bundle, which gets passed in when `onCreate()` is called. You could look into saving the state so that even if your app is killed (for memory) you can restore it.

Also I'd recommend using

```
ft.addToBackStack(null)
    .remove(CurrentFragment)
    .add(ToShowFragment)
    .commit()
```

So that you can make use of `popBackStack()` to easily handle adding and removing your Fragments. Also note `replace()` doesn't work with popping off the back stack as it's not reversed properly (you'll get state exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)` to keep the Fragment around, although this may work only for orientation changes, the docs are a little unclear.

Failing that there isn't a way that I know of to keep the Fragment around. Perhaps your best bet would be to save everything you want retained into a Bundle object in `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(..)`, and then read this data in either `Fragment.onCreate(..)` or `Fragment.onCreateView(..)`.

Another alternative, which I don't know much about, is using the `Fragment.SavedState` class, which seems to be similar to above except that you can save the state manually at any time. This would require a fair bit of coding on your part, but will give you greater control

Comment: setRetainInstance was helpful partly.  Didn't fix my problem, although I was having problems with switching orientations and that fixed it.
I tried saving my data in onSaveInstanceState, but it seems it's not called?  Is it supposed to be called when I press back to switch out of my activity?